# libc memory management

Tags: linux, memory-management, libc

How does libc communicate with the OS (e.g., a Linux kernel) to manage memory? Specifically, how does it allocate memory, and how does it release memory? Also, in what cases can it fail to allocate and deallocate, respectively?

Answer (score 3):

That is very general question, but I want to speak to the failure to allocate.  It's important to realize that memory is actually allocated by kernel upon first access.  What you are doing when calling `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` is reserving some addresses inside the virtual address space of a process (via syscalls `brk`, `mmap`, etc. `libc` does that).

When I get `malloc` or similar to fail (or when `libc` get `brk` or `mmap` to fail), it's usually because I exhausted the virtual address space of a process. This happens when there is no continuous block of free address, an no room to expand an existing one. You can either exhaust all space available or hit a limit RLIMIT_AS. It's pretty common especially on 32bit systems when using multiple threads, because people sometimes forget that each thread needs it's own stack.  Stacks usually consume several megabytes, which means you can create only few hundreds threads before you have no more free address space.  Maybe an even more common reason for exhausted address space are memory leaks.  `Libc` of course tries to reuse space on the heap (space obtained by a `brk` syscall) and tries to `munmmap` unneeded mappings. However, it can't reuse something that is not "deallocated".

The shortage of physical memory is not detectable from within a process (or libc which is part of the process) by failure to allocate.  Yeah, you can hit "overcommitting limit", but that doesn't mean the physical memory is all taken.  When free physical memory is low, kernel invokes special task called OOM killer (Out Of Memory Killer) which terminates some processes in order to free memory.

Regarding failure to `deallocate`, my guess is it doesn't happen unless you do something silly. I can imagine setting program break (end of heap) below it's original position (by a `brk` syscall).  That is, of course, recipe for a disaster.  Hopefully `libc` won't do that and it doesn't make much sense either. But it can be seen as failed deallocation.  `munmap` can also fail if you supply some silly argument, but I can't think of regular reason for it to fail.  That doesn't mean it doesn't exists.  We would have to dig deep within source code of glibc/kernel to find out.

Answer (score 2):

1) how does it allocate memory

libc provides malloc() to C programs.

> Normally, [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the
>   size of the heap as required, using sbrk(2). When allocating blocks of
>   memory larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, the glibc malloc()
>   implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping
>   using mmap(2). MMAP_THRESHOLD is 128 kB by default, but is adjustable
>   using mallopt(3). Allocations performed using mmap(2) are unaffected
>   by the RLIMIT_DATA resource limit (see getrlimit(2)).

And this is about sbrk.

> [sbrk](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk) - change data segment size

2) in what cases can it fail to allocate

Also from [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

> By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy.
>   This means that when malloc() returns non-NULL there is no guarantee
>   that the memory really is available.

And from [proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)

> /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
>       This file contains the kernel virtual memory accounting mode. Values are:
>
> 0: heuristic overcommit (this is the default)
>  
>   1: always overcommit, never check 
>   2: always check, never overcommit

Comment: "how does it allocate memory" - I'm sure OP was asking how `malloc()` does the trick, not "how do you allocate memory in C".

Comment: `malloc` was mentioned in order to tell about `sbrk`

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it uses the `sbrk` system call to adjust the size of the data segment, thereby reserving more memory for it to parcel out. Memory allocated in that way is generally not released back to the operating system because it is only possible to do it when the blocks available to be released are at the end of the data segment.

Larger blocks are sometime done by using `mmap` to allocate memory, and that memory can be released again with an `munmap` call.

Answer (score 1):

> How does libc communicate with the OS (e.g., a Linux kernel) to manage memory?

Through [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) - this is a low-level API that the kernel provides.

> Specifically, how does it allocate memory, and how does it release memory?

Unix-like systems provide the ["sbrk" syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbrk).

> Also, in what cases can it fail to allocate and deallocate, respectively?

Allocation can fail, for example, when there's no enough available memory. Deallocation shall not fail.

Comment: Don't forget `mmap` and `munmap` for allocating/releasing address space.  Also, memory allocation generally happens at page-fault time, not at `sbrk`/`mmap`/`munmap` time.  If overcommiting, the sbrk/mmap system call may succeed, but the page fault can trigger the out-of-memory failure.